# How do you draw a normal circle?

Tags: java, drawing

Just as the questions says..

I've been trying to make a circle on my JFrame but it keeps giving me an error

*my code:*

```
  public void paint(Graphics g) {

  }
```

*errors:*

```
public void paint() {

}
//error: void is an invalid type for the variable paint
```

2nd error

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

}
//error: Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
```

Comment: Your class is just the math model. I didn't know JFrame, unfortunately, but you need draw your shape using method of drawing that JFrame gives you and from your class you need to use data to specify shape parameters only. Or write a custom view if you need. So, you should extend your class from `JComponent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(0, 0, 300, 300);
}
```

`setColor` sets the color and fillOval fills an oval at 0, 0 with 300 radius.

First error explained: You have to have brackets.

Second error: where are the brackets?

Comment: I accidentally was putting the paint inside of main....